# Why does $\int \sec(x)dx=\ln|\tan(x)+\sec(x)| + C$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to figure out why  $\int \sec(x)dx=\ln|\tan(x)+\sec(x)| + C$. When I plugged it into [symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/integral-calculator/%5Cint%20sec%5Cleft(x%5Cright)dx), all it said was,

> Use the common integral: $\int \sec(x)dx=\ln|\tan(x)+\sec(x)|$

I don't know what it means by "common integral". What is a "common integral"? I know what an integral is, but I couldn't find a definition of "common integral" specifically.

Comment: Here is more https://www.intmath.com/methods-integration/table-common-integrals.php

Comment: Think about integrals of the form $f'/f$ that result in logs.  Now try to work back as suggested in answer.

Comment: I think common means like popular or well known here.

Comment: But If you take derivative of $Ln|tan(x)+Sec(x)|$, the result is not $Sec(x)$.Interested to where this result is come from.

Comment: @sirous The derivative may not look like $\sec(x)$ at first but after some simplification you will see that it is... also you must remember that there is an extra constant after you integrated it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Multiply numerator and denominator of $$\sec(x)$$ by $$\tan(x)+\sec(x)$$